# "Вечный цикл" в коде

Tags: javascript

Привет всем ещё раз. Сразу скажу что то, что это написано на чистом JS: так нужно автору. И да, я в курсе, что на jQuery уже есть куча готовых решений по этому поводу. Прошу помощи в другом. Есть скрипт, который меняет задний фон "плавно". Где-то в нём есть "вечный цикл", который я что-то пока не могу найти, вернее найти могу, а вот причину его вечных повторений нет. Прошу помощи. Сам скрипт:

```
 //Рандомно выбирает число
 function randomcolor(min_random, max_random) {
     var t = max_random - min_random + 1;
     return Math.floor(Math.random() * t) + min_random;
 }

 //Фунция для чтения значения свойства css
 function getStyle(el, styleProp) {
     var x = document.getElementById(el);
     if (x.currentStyle) var y = x.currentStyle[styleProp];
     else if (window.getComputedStyle) var y = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(x, null).getPropertyValue(styleProp);
     y = parseFloat(y);
     return y;
 }

 //Функция для "плавного" изменения цвета фона
 function change_color(color) {
     flag = 1;
     while (flag == 1) {
         opacity = getStyle('mainid', 'opacity');
         setTimeout('sopacity(opacity)', 100);
     }
     document.body.bgColor = color;
     flag = 1;
     opacity = getStyle('mainid', 'opacity');
     while (flag == 1) {
         setTimeout('mopacity(opacity)', 100);
     }
 }

 //Функция для постепенного уменьшения прозрачности body
 function sopacity(small_opacity) {
     if (small_opacity > 0.3) {
         small_opacity = small_opacity - 0.1;
         document.body.style.opacity = small_opacity;
     } else flag = 0;
 }

 //Функция для постепенного увеличения прозрачности body
 function mopacity(big_opacity) {
     if (big_opacity > 0.3) {
         big_opacity += 0.1;
         document.body.style.opacity = big_opacity;
         opacity = big_opacity;
     } else flag = 0;
 }

 //Точка входа 
 window.onload = function () {
     colors = ["#00FFFF", "#34985", "#0000FF", "#808080"];
     setInterval("change_color(colors[randomcolor(1,4) - 1])", 5000);
 }
```

Прошу гуру JS помочь мне выбраться из этой "индуской" ямы. Спасибо.

Comment: Вот на кой чёрт делать "сообщство хэшкод" в данном вопросе? И зачем вы опять сломали форматирование кода?

Comment: Индусскую яму вы вырыли себе без их (индусов) скромной помощи ;)

Comment: Вот на кой чёрт делать "сообщство хэшкод" в данном вопросе?<--Это вы о чём?
И зачем вы опять сломали форматирование кода?
Вроде бы не ломал ничего..

Comment: О том, что получается, что вопрос зада сообществом хэшкод, а не вами. Про форматирование.. странно.. даже очень.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Где то в нём есть "вечный цикл"

Так вот он

```
while (flag == 1)
{ ....
```

А причина в том, что flag всегда будет равен одному, потому что.. иное просто не предусмотрено. Наверное вы думаете, что flag = 0 в setopacity сделает его 0, но это не так. Эта функция не будет ни разу вызвана, потому что выполняющийся цикл не даст таймера сработать ни разу. Активные циклы никогда не применяются в JavaScript для ожидания какого-нибудь события.

Делается это примерно так

```
var currentOpacity = getOpacity();
var timer = null;

stop = function() {
    if (timer) {
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
};

start = function() {
    stop();

    timer = setInterval(function() {
        currentOpacity = Math.max(0, currentOpacity - 0.05);
        if (currentOpacity <= 0) {
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
        setOpacity(currentOpacity);
    }, 100);
};

getOpacity = function() {...}
setOpacity = function() { ... }
```

Comment: Только начинаю постигать основы JS. Спасибо. Буду знать.

Answer (score 1):

Какова задача? Написать скрипт, который постоянно плавно меняет задний фон (волнами, из светлого в тёмное, затем опять в светлое, опять в тёмное и т.д.), так?

Тогда всё действительно просто и без jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    loopOpacity(0, true);

    function loopOpacity(opcty, direction) {
        if (direction) {
            if (opcty < 0.9) {
                opcty += 0.1;
                if (opcty > 0.9) {
                    direction = false;
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (opcty > 0.1) {
                opcty -= 0.1;
                if (opcty < 0.1) {
                    direction = true;
                }
            }
        }
        setTimeout("loopOpacity(" + opcty + ", " + direction + ")", 100);
        document.getElementById("page").style.opacity = opcty;
    }
</script>
```

С цветом всё аналогично за исключением того, как именно увеличивается/уменьшается цвет.

Comment: Спасибо. Возьму на заметку ваш способ.